# Adjust tab content and background heights

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tabs

I have 2 tabs that lay on a block with a background image. Depending on which tab is clicked, the background image of the tabs and the tab content panel should change height. I cannot do it through CSS so I thought of using JS to change heights, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#two-tab').click(function() {
  $('.search-tabs').height('350px');
  $('#two-panel').height('272px')
});
```

```css
.search-tabs {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg')!important;
  background-position: center top!important;
  height: 281px!important;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.tab-radio{
    display:none;
}
#one:checked ~ .panels #one-panel,
#two:checked ~ .panels #two-panel{
   display:block
}
#one:checked ~ .tabs #one-tab,
#two:checked ~ .tabs #two-tab{
  background:#F5A000;
  color:#000;
}

.tab-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.panels {
  height: 229px;
  width: 333px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  border-top: 3px solid #F5A000;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  animation: fadein .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search-tabs">
  <div class="tab-wrapper">
  
    <input class="tab-radio" id="one" name="group" type="radio" checked>
    <input class="tab-radio" id="two" name="group" type="radio">
    
    <div class="tabs">
      <label class="tab" id="one-tab" for="one">Tab 1</label>
      <label class="tab" id="two-tab" for="two">Tab 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="panels">
      <div class="panel" id="one-panel">
        Content for tab 1
      </div>
      <div class="panel" id="two-panel">
        Content for tab 2
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code - for example: The content for the tabs is hidden by `display: none`. You defined the height for `.search-tabs` with `!important` which overwrites your js-action.

Comment: I would seek to remove IDs from your CSS _and_ your script. They're usually not necessary and they reduce reusability.

Comment: @biberman, you are right. The !important was causing the problem. Removed it and it is working now

Comment: I changed the comment to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the height for `.search-tabs` with `!important` which overwrites the height that you set in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

!! I added my own picture so you please swap it with a picture of your desire.

!! This is the only JavaScript code that you will need for this to work, The lines that you wrote, I deleted them

!! Add this code in the JavaScript file and delete the previous code that you wrote.

This piece of code will do the follows

1. If you click tab 2 it will change the height of the desired elements
2. If you click tab 1 it will bring all the elements back to their original form.

ps: when you copy this code in your editor, right-click on the display and click on format document or just click (shift + alt + f)

```
const searchContainer = document.querySelector(".search-tabs");

const panel = document.querySelector("#two-panel");

const tabOne = document.querySelector("#two-tab");
const tabTwo = document.querySelector("#one-tab");

let changingFunc = function(one, two) {
    searchContainer.style.height = `${one}`;
    panel.style.height = `${two}`;
};

const panelHeight = panel.offsetHeight;

tabOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    changingFunc("350px", "272px");
});

tabTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    changingFunc("281px", `${panelHeight}px`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kaleem bhatti for your suggestion. But your code does not change the panel's size. It changes the background image size but not the panel height

Comment: there are two panels, do you want the panels to change as well, with the height

Comment: This line: const panel = document.querySelector("#two-panel");
should change to this: const panel = document.querySelector(".panels");